# Lint: `x <> null`; suggestion consider using pattern matching

Tags: f#

The Lint of F# power tool suggests using pattern matching to replace `x <> null` in the following code (`when x <> null`).

```
let x = obj.method(...) // Call some C# library, may return null
match s with 
| ParseRegex "...." r when x <> null -> Some ( x |> ....) 
| _ -> None
```

1. Does another pattern pattern (removing the `when` part) make the code more cumbersome?
2. Why `x <> null` is bad?
3. How to rewrite the code in a better way?

Comment: I would write the code the same way you did it :-). The Linter is just giving suggestions - so I think there are situations where you do not necessarily need to follow it. The nicer thing about your version (compare to the one from Gustavo) is that you only end up with two branches rather than three...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, you can match both values in one shot:

```
let x = obj.method(...) // Call some C# library, may return null
match (s, x) with 
| (_, null) -> None
| (ParseRegex "...." r, _) -> Some ( x |> ....) 
| _ -> None
```

2) There are some performance issues explained [here](http://latkin.org/blog/2015/05/18/null-checking-considerations-in-f-its-harder-than-you-think/)

3) May be but you should describe a bit more your code, for instance where is r used on the left side?

Comment: For the code, I actually want to match the **not** null `x` for the first pattern matching.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer, see if it makes sense now. I'm not sure if you need the third guard for your specific problem.

Comment: Ad 2) Not to mention that matching against `null` propagates a null constraint only, `val x : 'a (requires 'a : null)`, while an equality-test will need an equality constraint as well. Considering constraint-free `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`, pattern matching is clearly preferred